# Hide paper-tab -- is it possible with Css

Tags: css, polymer

I'm creating an app that needs to be very mobile friendly. I have a simple Css class (.hide-mobile-small) that I use a media query to hide certain things on screen when device-width < 500.

It works on Divs (but isn't targeting divs only -- its defined as .hide-mobile-small  -- NOT div.hide-mobile-small).

I figured this should work on any polymer element as well.  I tried it on the paper-tab element because I want to hide some tabs on a multi-tab page layout when the user is viewing on a phone.  But it doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work without needing to update the paper-tab component?

Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: check weight of css selector for tabs. If tabs selectors more strong it's just override yours. Try in your class add `!important` to hide rule for exampe `display: none!important;`. Think it will help but it's not a good style of code. If it fix the problem then main problem was with selector weight and try build more strong and delete `!important`

Comment: Are you using Shadow DOM or Shady DOM? Maybe style encapsulation is preventing our styles from being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use CSS to hide a `<paper-tab>`.

For [example](http://jsbin.com/loxuzovogo/edit?html,output), you could hide any `<paper-tab>` that has the `hidden` class applied:

```
paper-tab.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

This [example](http://jsbin.com/yoqasimale/1/edit?html,output) uses a media query to hide the second tab when the width is less than 480px:

```
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    paper-tab:nth-of-type(2n) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>
<paper-tabs selected="0">
  <paper-tab>ITEM ONE</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>ITEM THREE</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```